# Redis CLI - WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I am new to redis.
I am trying to execute the below command.

```
HSET 1000:123:1603872000 "totalscore":100 "uid":"1000:123:1603872000"  "price": 1000  "points": 30
```

But this gives me below error

> (error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

```
type 1000:123:1603872000
```

This gives me type as string. How can I set string field values to a string key in redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for storing values in a hash map in redis is:
hset hash_map_name key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3

You don't have to separate key-value pair with a colon.
In the example below I am storing 3 keys named as name, website and age in a hash map named _my_hash_map.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset my_hash_map  name Ankit website StackOverflow age 100
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall my_hash_map
1) "name"
2) "Ankit"
3) "website"
4) "StackOverflow"
5) "age"
6) "100"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: Yes but this again gives me (error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value. HSET 1000:123:1603872000 totalscore "100"  uid  "1000:123:1603872000"  price "1000". But if I change key from 1000:123:1603872000 to 1000:123:160387200, no issues. TYPE 1000:123:1603872000 IS String and TYPE 1000:123:160387200 is hash

Comment: HSET 1000:123:1603872000 totalscore "100" uid "1000:123:1603872000" price "1000"
This did not give any error. Can you show the exact command that you entered and the exact error messae?

Comment: HSET 1000:123:1603872000 totalscore "100" uid "1000:123:1603872000" price "1000"

same command : (error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

Comment: is this because of any redis version difference? If I remove the last 0  in the key , I get sucess. So that's why I checked both of its type. TYPE 1000:123:1603872000 is string and TYPE 1000:123:160387200 is hash.

Comment: Can you run 
HGETALL 1000:123:1603872000
and see what the result is? If there is an pre-existing data, tr removing the hasmap by running 
del 1000:123:1603872000